# Roku Premiere hang and no logging

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have a screen graph application that works fine on Roku 2 and the new Roku Streaming stick.  The same zip deployed to the new Roku Premiere hangs when trying to load content into a RowList.

My Roku Premiere is only firmware 7.2.2.  My streaming stick is 7.5 (not sure what the Roku 2 is, as it is at home right now and I am at work).

I telnet to the Premiere and I get no errors.  The screen freezes and I have to press the reset button on the bottom of the premiere.

Another thing I notice on the premiere is my "print" statements on the render thread do not make it to the telnet output.  Print statements in my main thread work just fine.  I have a print statement in my component "init" method that does not get printed out.  This print statement is before the RowList content is changed (its the 1st statement in my components brs file).

Is there some known issue with screengraph and firmware 7.2?  Or some known issue with Premiere?

We are trying to bring quite a few roku apps to market and this is a serious issue for us

**Update:**  I was not aware that you had to [telnet into a different port](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Debugging+Scene+Graph+Applications) to get output for Render thread code in firmware < 7.5. Problem is some deadlock issue that does not exist in 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trackback: see https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=97519 for details

Briefly, rOS 7.5 changes debug console implementation - before each thread was going to separate port, now they are multiplexed to a single port.

Also a change, in rOS 7.2 and prior, the thread-locks can (and occasionally do) timeout/expire, in the process failing a get/set property between threads and leading to grim results. In the new versions they never expire, under the doctrine that the outcome will be less grim